# how can make button with Corner and gradient color in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

how can i make button with corners and gradient color in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the extension-

```
extension UIButton
{
func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor])
{
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
}
```

Comment: Why does the button look like this when I applied the code?

http://www.mediafire.com/file/liqv51ta7yqu4sx/Image+from+iOSs.png

Comment: @BasimHammad please check constraints or try to apply gradient in viewWillAppear